# How to identify a vCenter locator in vSphere?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

When deploying an OVA/OVF file to vCenter, `ovftool` requires a locator.

The example locator in the [user guide](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf20/ovftool_201_userguide.pdf) looks like this: `vi://user@localhost/Datacenter`

When I look at the vCenter path with vSphere, the hierarchy we have set up is:

```
    - Location
    -- Department with Spaces
    --- security_group
```

Perhaps my assumption that this hierarchy is the locator is incorrect, because `vi://user@localhost/Location/Department\ with\ Spaces/security_group` just returns `Error: Cannot parse VI locator`.

Is there a way in vSphere to determine the correct locator of a vcenter for an `ovftool` deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are specifying the --datastore, you'll want to use the `ovftool` auto-complete to suggest your path.  So in my case, I used `vi://user:password@localhost/Location/host` to identify both the vCenter locator and the datastore.  When you reach the end of the autocompletion, you have your datastore value `"Datastores found on target:"`, and the path prior is your locator.

Comment: This was extremely helpful even 4 years later